# How to mention full stack experience on my resume?

Tags: interviewing, software-industry, resume, job-search

I am a Product Engineer II at my current company.

I work on writing backend in Java, making and querying tables in SQL, adding front-end on web (AngularJS, HTML, CSS) and Android (xml, SQLite), creating ec2 instances on AWS, using Docker to containerize the web app, deploying the web app using Jenkins.

I am preparing my resume to switch my job.

How do I mention I have full stack experience without sounding phony?

[image: Current Position Resume Snapshot]

Comment: the second paragraph in your question explains full stack experience. Put that summarised.

Comment: Just say 'full stack'

Comment: ...after that please **change that 0% downtime**, they will think you don't know what you're talking about (or ask embarrassing questions during f2f interview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly the way you have described to us. - "Worked on writing backend in Java,... etc". If you are weaker in some technologies (or/and you want to improve at some) then you can mention it during the interview itself - nobody is an expert on everything but you can get stuff done end-to-end.

Also you have called yourself a "Product Engineer II" in your CV - personally I would either omit this title altogether or put it into parenthesis after the standard industry name for your position. Especialy if you want to get hired as such. So if you are a Full Stack Developer then call yourself like that.

Future companies care about who you are and not how you were called in the former company (which is not relevant to them). It will also help them when scanning your CV or when searching for you on some internet recruitment platform.